# How to drop a row of a pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, drop

Dataset

```
f = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4),columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

I tried the below way, but the column is not getting removed. Please help me!

```
f.drop([3])
f.head()
```

I even tried iloc method, but no improvements were there. Please help me!

Comment: Your title says drop row, then in your question you are talking about column, that's confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign it or adding `inplace`

```
f = f.drop([3]) # f.drop([3],inplace=True)
```

For column drop

```
f = f.drop(f.columns[3],axis=1)
Out[184]: 
    A   B   C
0   0   1   2
1   4   5   6
2   8   9  10
3  12  13  14
```